# Spring Boot Spring Security Login Redirection Issues

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security

I implemented the Spring Boot Spring Security for handling authentication.

But as soon as I implemented it I keep getting re-directed to the webjars js instead of the welcome page. Here is my code, please suggest what could be the problem.

header.jspf

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/fmt" prefix="fm"%>
<%@taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" prefix="form"%>

<html>
<head>
<title>Life Hacking Tech</title>
<link href="webjars/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/holdings.css"/>
</head>
<body>
```

login.jsp

```
<%@ include file="common/header.jspf" %>
<%@ include file="common/navigation.jspf" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="spring" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags" %>
<c:set var="contextPath" value="${pageContext.request.contextPath}"/>

<div class="container">
    <form method="POST" action="${contextPath}/login" class="form-signin">
        <h2 class="form-heading">Log in</h2>

        <div class="form-group ${error != null ? 'has-error' : ''}">

            <input name="username" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Username" autofocus="autofocus"/>
            <input name="password" type="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Password"/>
            <span>${message}</span>
            <span>${error}</span>
            <input type="hidden" name="${_csrf.parameterName}" value="${_csrf.token}"/>

            <button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" type="submit">Log In</button>
            <h4 class="text-center"><a href="${contextPath}/registration">Create an account</a></h4>
        </div>

    </form>

</div>
<%@ include file="common/footer.jspf" %>
```

LoginController.java

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/login", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String login(Model model, String error, String logout) {
    if (error != null)
        model.addAttribute("error", "Your username and password is invalid.");

    if (logout != null)
        model.addAttribute("message", "You have been logged out successfully.");

    return "loginPost";
}

@RequestMapping(value = {"/", "/welcome"}, method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String showPage(ModelMap model) {
        model.addAttribute("uname", getLoggedInUserName());
        return "welcome";
}
```

SecurityConfiguration.java

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter{


    @Autowired
    private UserDetailsService userDetailsService;

    @Bean
    public BCryptPasswordEncoder bCryptPasswordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
        .authorizeRequests()
        .antMatchers("/registration").permitAll().anyRequest().authenticated()
        .antMatchers("/css/**", "/login").permitAll()       
        .antMatchers("/","/*todo*/**").authenticated()
        .antMatchers("/*holding*/**").authenticated()
        .and().formLogin()./*successHandler(authSuccessHandler()).*/loginPage("/login").permitAll()
        .and().logout().permitAll()
        .logoutRequestMatcher(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/logout"))
        .and().exceptionHandling()
        .accessDeniedPage("/access-denied");
    }

    @Bean
    public AuthenticationSuccessHandler authSuccessHandler(){
        return new SimpleUrlAuthenticationSuccessHandler();
    }

    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService).passwordEncoder(bCryptPasswordEncoder());
    }

}
```

After a successful login I get re-directed to the scripts in footer.jsp

footer.jspf

```
    <script src="webjars/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="webjars/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="webjars/bootstrap-datepicker/1.0.1/js/bootstrap-datepicker.js"></script>
    <script>
        $('#targetDate').datepicker({

        })
    </script>
    <script>
    $('.nav li').click(function(e) {
        $('.nav li.active').removeClass('active');
        var $this = $(this);
        if (!$this.hasClass('active')) {
            $this.addClass('active');
        }
    });
    </script>  
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same issue. Adding

```
.antMatchers("webjars/**").permitAll()
```

to the SecurityConfiguration did the trick.